# Использование памяти сборщиком мусора Golang

Tags: golang, memory

У меня программа использует более чем `900МБ ОЗУ`. Просто выводит бесконечное количество раз `Hello World` и работает на 10 горутинах. У меня возник вопрос ***что будет если запустить ту же программу на компютере где будет не более 512 МБ ОЗУ***. Программу сразу же выбьет из процесса или она будет идти до лимита и выделять нужное количество `ОЗУ` для своей работы? И можно ли как-то ограничить потребляемость памяти.

Comment: Что будет, вы легко можете выяснить в виртуальной машине.

Comment: @D-side понятное дело что в виртуалке можно протестировать, но у меня её под рукой нету. А если вы не можете ответить или чем-то помочь то лучше не отвечайте вообще.

Comment: Хе. За те полчаса, что вы уже ждёте ответа, вы могли узнать ответ на свой вопрос сами. Но дело ваше.